# jquery previous element with several classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got this structure of table :

```
<tr class="dossier">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail alert">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dossier">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even dossier">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="detail alert">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

When a tr element has `alert` class, I have to add `alert` class to the previous element with `dossier` class.

I try this code :

```
$("tr.alert").prev("tr.dossier").addClass("alert");
```

This is working only with `<tr class="dossier">` elements. It doesn't work with`<tr class="even dossier">` elements.

Has somebody a way to do this ?

Comment: `$("tr.alert").prevUntil('tr.alert', "tr.dossier").addClass("alert");`

Comment: How about this $("tr.alert").prev("tr.dossier, tr.even.dossier").addClass("alert");

Comment: `$("tr.alert").prev("tr.dossier, tr.even.dossier").addClass("alert");` has the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below explanation is in the context of my example code at the end of my answer.

First of all since you have multiple `tr.alert`'s you will need to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) as you are wanting to add your class to the closest `tr.dossier` to each `tr.alert` but leaving the middle `tr.dossier` unchanged.

Using `$("tr.alert").prev("tr.dossier")` will only return the immediately preceding element and only then if that element is a `tr` with the class `dossier`.  If you want an element that is further back through the DOM you will need to use `$("tr.alert").prevAll("tr.dossier")`.

However simply using `$("tr.alert").prevAll("tr.dossier")` will return all previous `tr`'s with the class `dossier` for each `tr.alert` and then combine them into one collection.  In the case of your DOM jQuery will return the first `tr.dossier` for your first `tr.alert` and all three for the last one.  Those four results will then be reduced to the three actual items available in the DOM.

From there you can use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to select an individual item but it will only select the `tr.dossier` preceding either your first or last `tr.alert` and won't be applied to both (as it appears you require).  Using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) will allow you to deal with each `tr.alert` individually and find it's nearest `tr.dossier`.

In this example the rows with the class `dossier` have a green background and those with `alert` have their font size set to `50px`.

```js
$("tr.alert").each(function(index, me) {
  $(me).prevAll("tr.dossier").first().addClass("alert");
});
```

```css
tr.alert {
  font-size: 50px;
}
tr.dossier {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice approach to include in selector the class. You don't need the extra `if` I had in my code.

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate through `tr` elements and check if have class `alert`. Then you can check the previous elements that has class `dossier` and add class `alert` to that element:

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("alert")) {
    $(this).prevAll("tr.dossier").first().addClass("alert");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is only working if the `detail alert` tr is just after the `dossier` element.

Comment: @user3469203 You want the first previous element with class `dossier`?

Comment: @user3469203 Glad that I helped you.

Comment: your `$(this).prevAll("tr.dossier").first()` is much better than my `$($("tr.alert").prevAll("tr.dossier")[0])`. Nice work :)

Comment: To be honest @AmmarCSE didn't check other answers. Thanks for your positive comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**prevAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

```js
$($("tr.alert").prevAll("tr.dossier")[0]).addClass("alert");
```

```css
.alert{
font-weight: bold;
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even dossier">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail alert">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to add `alert` class only to the one `dossier` element that is before. `prevAll` gets **all** `dossier` elements.

Comment: I just need to add alert class to the first previous element with dossier class. prevAll() will add the alert element to all the previous dossier elements. It's not what I want to do.

Comment: I've tried Alex Char solution that is working. Yours is quiet the same so It might work too